# Cannot find UploadedFiles class for import in PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces

In my jsf managed bean file I am not able to import the `UploadedFiles`  class of PrimeFaces; No dependency seems to contain it.

I tried upgrading PrimeFaces jar version to 7 but didn't find in it also.

I want multiple file upload feature.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You cannot import ANY dependency for PrimeFaces UploadedFiles? What dependency did you try and what dependency do you think you need? And what are the errors? And.... Please desecribe as a developer

Comment: OK! I have added a image for your reference. UploadedFiles class cannot be found.

Comment: So you cannot import the CLASS `UploadedFiles`? Nothing to do with 'dependencies' Tried PF  8? Tried  a searchengine: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=PrimeFaces+%22UploadedFiles%22  Tried the PF issues? Tried the PF source?

Answer (score 3):

`UploadedFiles` was introduced in PrimeFaces 8